# Relative performance of the Julia language

Tags: memoization, julia

I was just reviewing the *Mathematica* benchmark code linked from the Julia language home page http://julialang.org/. The stated goal of the benchmarks is to test the performance of specific algorithms, expressed in a *reasonable idiom* in each language, and all languages use the same algorithm.

In particular, the Fibonacci benchmarks are all recursive, and the *Mathematica* code reads

```
ClearAll[fib];
fib = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
    If[n < 2, n, fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]],
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
];
```

Now, dynamic programming is certainly a *reasonable idiom* in *Mathematica*:

```
fib[n_Integer]:= fib[n]= If[n < 2, n, fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]]
```

and this dynamic *uncompiled* code will be much faster than the benchmark code, especially for large n (unless the WVM compiler is smart enough to do automatic memoization).

The test only computes fib[20] and it would be most interesting to try say fib[100] in the various languages (the times for R, MATLAB, and OCTAVE are excessive even for n=20).

It would also be useful, I think, for better coding of all the benchmark examples, if someone has the time and energy ...

Comment: You know that self-answering is not at all frowned upon? ;-)

Comment: For the Fibonacci example, this might be related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31593/fibonacci-sequence-generator

Comment: What exactly is the question? This is a Q&A site after all...

Comment: One could interpret this as a question along the lines "Do people have input on better Mathematica coding of examples in ...?"

Comment: It looks like everything is using `Compile`.  I wouldn't write code like this for the benchmark.  Even if in some cases the compiled code is faster, it is not natural for Mathematica.  I'd only use Compile in cases when it's clearly the best approach, e.g. the mandelbrot test.  I did write a set of Mathematica benchmarks when Julia was first made public, but I got lazy at the quicksort and stopped there.  I hacve the rest, should dig them up.

Comment: I did look at this code the other day.  It is not all idiomatic Mathematica.  Compile is in particular overused.  But it does run very fast.  It looks like whoever wrote it put in considerable effort to make it run fast.  This is not unidiomatic because the programmer didn't know Mathematica well.  It's like that because it's optimized for speed.  It is definitely an advantage of Mathematica that memoization is easy, and the Fibonacci implementation you show is indeed the most idiomatic fast implementation.  The problem is that the algorithm it uses differs from the code in other languages.

Comment: It's possible to do memoization in other languages too, it just takes (a lot?) more work.  Since this benchmark is primarily meant to compare speed (not how easy the language is to use), it wouldn't be fair to use the memoized Fibonacci code ...

Comment: never understood why Fibonacci code (like factorials) are always expressed recursively when linearly implementing the algorithm  is pretty simple and straightforward

Comment: @Szabolcs In Julia it is also easy to memoize (you need a package, https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Memoize.jl). It could be interesting to compare memoized implementations.

Answer (score 14):

I wrote the code in question... It is pretty much a line for line port of the Julia version of the benchmark:

Julia:

```
fib(n) = n < 2 ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Mathematica:

```
fib = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
    If[n < 2, n, fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]],
    CompilationTarget -> "WVM" 
    (* WVM is faster than C in this case because of the recursive calls *)
];
```

It was never intended it to be an example of idiomatic Mathematica code. I did however actively chose not to use memoization because the benchmark states: "all languages use the same algorithm".

On my use of Compile: Since the code is very procedural it was very amenable to use with Compile. Most of the time it was as simple as wrapping the functions with Compile. I do recognize that it is sort of gaming the benchmark and perhaps it should have been excluded.

I am open to doing a rewrite of the code that does things in a more idiomatic style if there is any interest but I doubt the people over at Julia really care much.

(Sorry this isn't just a comment. I don't have the reputation to make comments)

Edit: I just tested the more idiomatic:

```
ClearAll[fib];
fib[0] = 0;
fib[1] = 1;
fib[n_] := fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2];
```

It turns out this is only about 3 times slower than the WVM compiled version.

Comment: Fair enough. But...for some reason I did not find the `fib` Julia code at the linked-to site. Could you show that? (Or at least tell me where I should have been looking.)

Comment: The `fib` code can be found here: 
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/test/perf/micro/perf.jl


Code for the other benchmarks is in the /julia/test/perf/micro/ folder:
https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/tree/master/test/perf/micro

Comment: Thanks. Also, if I understand the result, the WVM-interpreted flavor is a couple of orders of magnitude slower than a from-scratch C-compiled code? I'm seeing a bit under .01 sec for `fib[20]` and around 4.5 sec for `fib[34]`.

Comment: Yes. According to the table on http://julialang.org/ the WVM `fib` function is 163.43 times slower than the C version.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Roman E. Maeder gave ten progressively faster programs to compute Fibonacci numbers to illustrate optimization techniques applicable to other problems as well in *Fibonacci on the Fast Track* <https://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v1i3/tutorials/maeder/index.html> back in 1991.