# ReplaceRepeated as a Looping construct?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, core-language, iterators, infinite-loop

There are a lot of discussions about [looping constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LoopingConstructs.html) (notable example [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica)).
Wolfram language guides, as usually, contain most relevant links.

**Looping constructs** guide has the following part on the screen.

[image]

The link [`ReplaceRepeated`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPrKN.png) has its place of honor. Nonetheless, if you follow the link "Iterating over lists and expressions [>>](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html)", `ReplaceRepeated` is absent. Its own page is rather laconic and has no reference to looping.

As a typical case, I have not noticed Rule-base sample among 'Multiparadigm Language' examples of the **compounding** task on the ads [page](http://www.wolfram.com/finance-platform/compare-wolfram-finance-platform/index.en.html?footer=lang).
You may see that for 'functional paradigm' stands some:

```
NestList[# (1 + r) &, s, 3]
```

> `{s, (1 + r) s, (1 + r)^2 s, (1 + r)^3 s}`

I could imagine something for this compounding task:

```
ReplaceRepeated[s, s -> s (1 + r), MaxIterations -> 3]
```

but it gives a warning message (by the way, how to apply a shortcut `//.` to assume Option `MaxIteration`?).

> `ReplaceRepeated::rrlim: Exiting after s scanned 3 times. >>>`
>
> `(1 + r)^3 s`

So, my **question** is twofold. How to efficienly apply `ReplaceRepeated` for looping and what are textbooks examples of 'Rule-based programming style' (or Transformation Rules) applications for looping.
After all, what is the equivalent for `NestList` with `ReplaceRepeated`?

Comment: In that page it says **"supporting many programming paradigms, such as procedural, functional, rule-based, pattern-based, object-oriented, and more."**

Comment: As for "efficiency", you may find lot of questions on this site about efficiency and rules. It mainly depends on how you use blank patterns

Comment: @belisariushassettled, i.e. i.e. how blank patterns mimic the structure of compounding

Comment: Seems like your question is overly too broad

Comment: @belisariushassettled, you are authorised to decide. But saying **"supporting many programming paradigms, such as procedural, functional, rule-based, pattern-based, object-oriented, and more."** they provide all but no rule-based, pattern-based examples.

Comment: @belisariushassettled, to keep it simple, how to get '{s(1+r), s(1+r)^2, s(1+r)^3...}' with blank patterns or whatever that is 'rule-based approach'

Comment: You'll need to specify a stopping condition, like  `MaxIterations` or manually `k = s;
c = 0;
k //. s :> (c++; s (1 + r)) /; c < 3`

Comment: @belisariushassettled, `MaxIterations` gives me warining, `ReplaceRepeated::rrlim: Exiting after s scanned 3 times`. Manual stuff looks not much better than `For` loop. My example corrodes to `Union@Flatten@
  Quiet@ReplaceRepeated[s, s -> {s, s (1 + r)}, MaxIterations -> 3]`. I'm not sure that its a good candidate for the task. Why is it on the 'Looping construct guide'?

Comment: Well, it is a `ReplaceAll` with  `FixedPoint`. And `FixedPoint` is an iterative construct ...

Comment: @belisariushassettled, if that is all about `ReplaceAll`, that crutch would suffice: `Range[3] /. n_Integer :> s (1 + r)^n`. But that is a bit different story.

Comment: @Karsten, am I right to say that `Quiet@` is inevitable and my example `DeleteDuplicates@
 Flatten@Quiet@
   ReplaceRepeated[s, s -> {s, s (1 + r)}, MaxIterations -> 3]` is a good MMA practice?

Comment: I don't consider that message a "warning message". For me it's an information message, telling me that the rule could be applied more times. Instead of `Quiet` one could also use `Off[ReplaceRepeated::rrlim]`. There is also nothing wrong with getting that message printed.

Comment: I wouldn't consider [that example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101118/replacerepeated-as-a-looping-construct#comment274421_101118) good Mma practice, because other functions might be more suitable and you are using a lot of extra functions to make it work. If I'd have to use `ReplaceRepeated` to get that output I'd probably use something like `ReplaceRepeated[{s}, {most___, rest_} :> {most, rest, rest /. s -> s (1 + r)}, MaxIterations -> 3]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the shortcut `//.` together with a `MaxIterations` options

```
s //. Sequence[s -> s (1 + r), MaxIterations -> 3]
```

$\ $`(1 + r)^3 s`

or

```
s //. (s -> s (1 + r)) ~ Sequence ~ (MaxIterations -> 3)
```

---

An example for an efficient looping construct using `ReplaceRepeated` is the [pattern matching Fibonacci sequence generator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/97016/18476)

```
fiboSequence2[n_] := 
 Quiet@ReplaceRepeated[{0, 1}, {x___, a_, b_} :> {x, a, b, a + b}, MaxIterations -> n - 1]

fiboSequence2[15]
```

$\ $`{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610}`

---

The output of

```
NestList[# (1 + r) &, s, 3]
```

can be reproduced with

```
ReplaceRepeated[{s}, 
  {most___, rest_} :> {most, rest, rest /. s -> s (1 + r)}, MaxIterations -> 3]
```

$\ $`{s, (1 + r) s, (1 + r)^2 s, (1 + r)^3 s}`

or

```
{s} //. {most___, rest_} /; Length[{most}] < 3 :> {most, rest, rest (1 + r)}
```

$\ $`{s, (1 + r) s, (1 + r)^2 s, (1 + r)^3 s}`

Answer (score 3):

Check out David Wagner's Power Programming with Mathematica, chapter6, Ruled-based programming. 
(Refer to this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16485/are-you-interested-in-purchasing-david-wagners-power-programming-with-mathemat) to obtain the download link.)

From Section 6.2.6 Pure ruled-based programming, the author shares the following example using **ReplaceRepeated** to define the **Factorial** function on the fly.

```
f[5] //. {f[0]:>1,f[n_]:>n*f[n-1]}
```

For the Compounded interest rate, using the method above, the definition would be as follows.

```
cI[interest_, 
  periods_] := (1 + interest)^
   periods //. (1 + interest) ^
    periods :> (1 + interest) (1 + interest)^(periods - 1)

cI[0.1,12]
(*3.14*)
```

For the Fibonacci function:

```
fibo[12] //. {fibo[0] :> 0, fibo[1] :> 1, 
  fibo[n_] :> fibo[n - 1] + fibo[n - 2]}
(*144*)
```

Comment: @Karsten7, thanks, it is the factorial function.

Comment: With respect to efficiency your on the fly Fibonacci function is more a how not to use `ReplaceRepeated` example.  There are many more efficient ways to program a on the fly Fibonacci function using `ReplaceRepeated`.