# Nested function with an increasing argument

Tags: functions, programming, evaluation, syntax

If, for example, I have a nesting function like

```
Nest[1 + x^n (#) &, 1, 3]
```

it gives the result

```
1 + x^n (1 + x^n (1 + x^n))
```

I would need the `n` to increase by one with every step, just like in a sum or product function, so that the result would be

```
1 + x^1 (1 + x^2 (1 + x^3))
```

Is there a way to do this in *Mathematica*? If so, how?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Module[{i = 1}, Nest[1 + x^n (#) &, 1, 3] /. n :> i++]
```

[image]

Or (same result)

```
Fold[1 + x^#2 #1 &, 1, {3, 2, 1}]
```

Comment: +1 for `Module` construct.

Answer (score 6):

Taking a different approach it appears that you are seeking to apply Horner's Method to the polynomial

$$\underset{i=0}{\overset{n}{\sum }}x^{\underset{j=0}{\overset{i}{\sum }}j}$$

Taking $\underset{j=0}{\overset{i}{\sum }}j = \frac{1}{2}i(1+i)$ and making use of `HornerForm` a function can be created to construct the factored polynomial.

```
f[n_Integer?Positive] := HornerForm@Sum[x^(i (1 + i)/2), {i, 0, n}]
```

You are seeking `f[3]`

```
f[3]
(* 1 + x (1 + x^2 (1 + x^3)) *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

In case the intermediate result `1 + x^n (1 + x^n (...))` is not required,

```
n = 3;
First@Nest[{1 + x^#[[2]] #[[1]], #[[2]] - 1} &, {1, n}, n]
```

**Alternative**

A simpler formulation under the same assumption as above

```
n = 3;
Nest[1 + x^(n--) # &, 1, n]
```

Comment: +1 for `(n - -)` construct

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Fold`.

```
Fold[1 + x^#2 (#1) &, 1, Range[3, 1, -1]]
(*  1 + x (1 + x^2 (1 + x^3))  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Two approaches with Replacement**.

---

```
z = Nest[1 + x^n (#) &, 1, 3]
ReplacePart[z, Position[z, n][[#]] -> Defer@# & /@ Range[3]]
```

[image]

---

Also inspired by the @Karsten7's [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101118/replacerepeated-as-a-looping-construct/101154#101154) and @Eldo's Module version:

```
Module[{r = 3, i = 1}, 
Quiet@ReplaceRepeated[(1 + x^n), (1 + x^n) -> 1 + x^n (1 + x^n), 
MaxIterations -> r - 1] /. n :> i++]
```

> `1 + x (1 + x^2 (1 + x^3))`

Comment: Some more inspiration: `Module[{n = 3}, ReplaceRepeated[(1 + x^n), p_Plus /; n > 1 :> 1 + x^(--n)  p]]`