# Solving an inequality involving the Fibonacci function

Tags: inequalities

How can I solve an inequality that involves the Fibonacci function? For instance, say I want to determine for which values of $n$ we get that $$F_n\leqslant 1000.$$
I tried to use `Solve` and `Reduce`, like this,

```
Reduce[(Fibonacci[n] < 40) && n \[Element] Integers, {n}]
```

But I get, in both cases, this error code: “This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce (or Solve)”.

One alternative solution is to use plots, but this wont work if we're dealing with large values, example, $$F_n\leqslant 4.183713\cdot10^{11}.$$

So how to solve these type of inequalities manually?

Comment: In the help NestWhile[(# + 1) &, 1, Fibonacci[#] < 1000 &]

Comment: Could use the method [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math.symbolic/3Or8fZT-RAk) to invert the equality, then adjust for inequality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented:

```
    f[x] := NestWhile[(# + 1) &, 1, Fibonacci[#] <= x &,   1, \[Infinity], -1]
```

For 1000:

```
f[1000]
```

> 16

For your large number:

```
f[4.183713*10^11]
```

> 57

To make sure:

```
Fibonacci[57] < 4.183713*10^11 < Fibonacci[58]
```

gives `True`.

Comment: `Fibonacci[58]` is 591286729879 which greater than 4.183713*10^11

Comment: @BlacKow You were right, it was always off by one index. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
fibbo[n_Integer] := Fibonacci[Range[Floor[Log[GoldenRatio, Sqrt[5]*n + 1/2]]]]

fibbo[10000]
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765}
> ```

And see here [Fibonacci Sequence Generator](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31593/fibonacci-sequence-generator?rq=1)